# Angle brackets around the function < f(x) > notation meaning

Tags: functions, notation

I've seen it several times in papers, but I can't understand the point. I've seen the same equations without the brackets as well. Are they trying to emphasize something?
[image: angle brackets around the function]

[image]

Comment: Seems to be the definition of "mean value"

Comment: The author appears never to have been graced with a visit from the \langle \rangle fairy, whose $\langle \mathrm{sparkles} \rangle$ wane as the knowledge of the ancient sigils dies :(

Comment: @Randall The more I read those papers the more it seems to mean "smoothed approximation" of a function, which is linked with the mean value of course too. Probably some niche notation abuse though.

Comment: @PatrickStevens  LOL